# with CentOS 6.x minimal install I cannot start iptables

Tags: centos, ansible

I'm currently working on a Ansible playbook that attempts to install and start the iptables firewall on a CentOS 6.8 minimal install. I'm doing the following in Ansible.

```
### sets up FW pkgs
- name: Install FW packages
  hosts: elasticsearch-servers
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: install ipset
      yum: name={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
        - ipset
        - iptables

    - name: start iptables service
      service: name=iptables state=started enabled=yes
```

This however results in this:

```
TASK [start iptables service] **************************************************
fatal: [10.40.3.246]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "iptables: No config file.[WARNING]\r\n"}
fatal: [10.40.3.254]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "iptables: No config file.[WARNING]\r\n"}
fatal: [10.40.3.164]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "iptables: No config file.[WARNING]\r\n"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this appears to be a problem that showed up after CentOS 6.5. There's this customer portal topic on it, titled: [iptables failed to start in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6 and above versions of minimal installation.](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1361093).

The direct problem is the absence of the `/etc/sysconfig/ip*` files that the iptables service requires to start. You can force the creation of these files by running a `service iptables save`, however out of the box this will fail too, because kernel modules are required in order to run `service iptables save`.

This is a bit of a catch 22!

The easiest way to work around this is by inducing the loading of these 2 kernel modules:

- iptables_filter
- ip_tables

by running a `iptables` command:

```
$ iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

You'll see the modules loaded now:

```
$ lsmod | grep iptable
iptable_filter          2793  0
ip_tables              17831  1 iptable_filter
```

You can then do a `service iptables save` to get the missing files created, and thus start the iptables service.

#### Ansible

The above is interesting but not really very friendly to doing through Ansible, without enlisting the help of the `command:` and `shell:` modules.

However we can use the `modules:` module in Ansible to guarantee the loading/unloading of kernel modules.

For example:

```
### sets up FW pkgs
- name: Install FW packages
  hosts: elasticsearch-servers
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: install ipset
      yum: name={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
        - ipset
        - iptables

    # these next 2 tasks work around issue with iptables RPM in CentOS 6.5+
    # REF: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1361093
    - name: load ip_tables kernel module
      modprobe: name=iptable_filter state=present

    - name: initial save iptables generate files
      command: /sbin/service iptables save
      args:
        warn: false

    - name: start iptables service
      service: name=iptables state=started enabled=yes
```

In the above we're making sure that the iptable_filter is present before we attempt to do the save.

#### References

- [ansible module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/modprobe_module.html)
- [iptables failed to start in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6 and above versions of minimal installation.](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1361093)